# Android Spannable dismiss after editing

Tags: android-layout, android-view, android

I am implementing mentions as in twitter @username. But mentions can't be typed, only selected from MultiAutoCompleteTextView.

I am creating spannable with blue text color on treminateToken

```
Spannable sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
sp.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

But the problem is that user can edit this text.
How to make this snap non editable? To delete whole span when user press backspace?
Or at least change color back to black if it have been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Pass your string to this below method using key listener of your editext

```
public void displayText(String s)
{
    String ss[]=s.split(",");
    for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
    {
        final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        TextView tv = createContactTextView(ss[i]);
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) GlobalMethods.convertViewToDrawable(tv);
        bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(),bd.getIntrinsicHeight());

        sb.append(ss[i] + ",");
        sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), sb.length()-(ss[i].length()+1), sb.length()-1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        contact.setText(sb);//your edit text here
    }
}
```

set text style

```
public TextView createContactTextView(String text)
    {
      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setText(text);
      tv.setTextSize(25);
      tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.design);
      return tv;
    }
```

**Output:**
if the user try to delete the text it delete the whole text